# determine if mysql values are in same row

Tags: php, mysql

How would this be done? I would like to search the database row by row. I might even print out the entire list of the database row by row. But I would also like to show record 1400 for example and determine the info on that row - such as name, gender and country.

Is it possible to use the rownum function to get this done? Or would I need to use a where in the query? But even so how would I determine the row number? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "record 1400" - the 1400th record that was inserted?

Comment: Does your database have an `id` column?

Comment: yes it has an id column, and yes the 1400th record inserted

Answer (score 0):

Make one column as `ID`, make it PK and auto_increment. Then your query shell be something like this for #1400 row:

```
$pdo
  ->prepare(
     "SELECT `name`, `gender`, `country`
      FROM `foo_table` WHERE `id` = :id"
  )
  ->execute([':id' => 1400]);
```

Comment: thanks. How would I show the list of names using this setup in php. Sorry but I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

You can use user defined variables to get your rownumber in MySQL

```
set @nr = 0;
```

Now you can use this variable (same connection!) in your query

```
SELECT 
    @nr := (@nr + 1) rownumber,
    *
FROM
    table
```

see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-variables.html

Answer (score 0):

do your select and add

```
LIMIT n,1
```

this will skip to n-th element(1400) and show just one result